# How to know if slideToggle() moves upward or downward?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How does this code determine either to toggle upwards or toggle downwards? Please help out. Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".flip").click(function(){
                    $(".panel").slideToggle();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css"> 
            div.panel,p.flip {
                margin:0px;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                background:#e5eecc;
                border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }
            div.panel {
                height:120px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Crap.</p>
        </div>
        <p class="flip">Show/Hide Panel</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if the element is visible or not. If it's visible, `slideToggle()` will move up. If it's not visible, it will move down.

```
// Want to know if it's visible?
$(this).is(":visible");
```

You could also determine the direction it took *after the fact* as well:

```
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow", function(){
  alert( "I moved " + $(this).is(":visible") ? "Down" : "Up" );
})
```

This is, of course, assuming you don't have any positioned element, which it looks as though you don't.

Answer (score 2):

If the element is currently set to display: none; or is hidden in some other way. Height 0 for example. Then it will slide down, otherwise it will slide up.

Right now, that code will slide down as your CSS has display:none; in it.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether the content that is going to be toggled is visible or not

Answer (score 1):

Directly from jQuery site here (http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline. When the height reaches 0 after a hiding animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the jquery css function as,
I am writing the javaScript code here with some more changes in the code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
       if($(".panel").css("display") == 'block') {
          alert('Visible');
       } else {
          alert('Not visible');
       }
    $(".panel").slideToggle();
  });
});​
```

Please refer complete working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbSmH/)

Comment: Depending on your need do you want the alert before of after operation move the if block I have added before or after the slideToggle function call.